# Selenium Chromedriver Starts Hidden and Version Compatibility

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to execute Selenium test cases on Chrome browser. When I'm running the test cases on Chrome, Chrome browser is opened (in the background) and test cases are running as expected. The problem is, while running the test cases, Chrome browser doesn't appear as an active window, and below is the text that I got in the console:

```html
Starting ChromeDriver 2.22.397929 (fb72fb249a903a0b1041ea71eb4c8b3fa0d9be5a) on port 28568
Only local connections are allowed.
```

Versions used:
Chrome browser: 51.0.2704.103,
ChromeDriver: 2.22,
Selenium Standalone Server: 2.53.0,
IDE: IntelliJ on Mac

Below is the code i am using for chrome browser:

```js
case "Chrome": {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/main/resources/chromedriver");
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                break;
            }
```

Below is the POM.xml details:

```html
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Same test cases are working fine on Firefox (43.0).
Please let me know if I am doing something wrong or if I have to change the versions that I am using. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you're using `new ChromeDriver()` then you're not using selenium standalone server to run your tests.

Comment: I think instead of saying selenium standalone server i should say selenium webdriver...correct me if i am wrong. And in case of selenium webdriver can you please help me in understanding what's happening wrong.

Comment: @ankit I don't understand the problem. It opens the browser and the tests are running as expected. What exactly is it you expect too happen instead?

Comment: @RamcoW: The problem is it is opening the chrome browser, but not making it active while test cases are running. I am not able to see what is happening in browser until i am not explicitly clicking on browser icon to make it visible. Hope it clears the problem.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just going to the background because you're doing work on your computer and clicking somewhere?

Comment: Yes i am sure. I tried many time and every time i got same behavior. And when browser open, getting some message on console: "Starting ChromeDriver 2.22.397929 (fb72fb249a903a0b1041ea71eb4c8b3fa0d9be5a) on port 28568
Only local connections are allowed".I have tried finding the reason for this so somewhere saw that it happens because of compatibility issue but i am not sure.

Comment: Just now I figured out the solution, I have updated the Run configuration setting, In the JDK setting/Vm options added "-Dwindow.hide=false", and now it is working fine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's get some things straight:

1. If you want to check your compatibility of chromedriver and Chrome you can read it in the [notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.25/notes.txt) of the latest chromedriver.
2. You don't need compatibility between selenium-server since you're not using it, you're using the local chromedriver and it's more related to Chrome version rather than to Selenium jar.
3. The console output you published is just fine, it's the expected log for starting chromedriver.

   > Starting ChromeDriver 2.22...

Another solution to what you added in the comments  (`-Dwindow.hide=false`) may be to use a property in the chromedriver's DesiredCapabilities or ChromeOptions:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

And you can do [much more](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities) with these options.